# ASP.NET pages look different locally vs on server

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Developing locally in Visual Studio 2010 my page looks great.  When I deploy to the development server there is extra spacing and font size differences that mess things up.

Maybe it is because locally the Visual Studio rendering engine is iis7 vs on the development sever it is iis6.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks!!

Mark

Comment: IIS got nothing to do with the page look and visual design. Anyway, don't use the internal Visual Studio browser, right click the page and choose "View in browser" to open it with "real" browser like IE, FF or Chrome.

Comment: Shadow Wizard - Can you repost this as an Answer so I can mark it as answser?  Thanks!

Comment: Sure, done that now. By the way, use `@` to notify, in this case it worked because I'm the only one leaving comment but when there are two or more, there'll be no notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS got nothing to do with the page look and visual design.

You're probably viewing the page via the internal Visual Studio browser - don't do that.

Instead, right click the page and choose "View in browser" to open it with "real" browser like IE, FF or Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

You mean pages look different when viewed from the *same* browser? The only thing I can imagine is that you're missing some files (like CSS) when deploying.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably got something to do with the IE Compatibility settings.

When you browse an intranet site; IE, by default, displays it in Compatibility View. So you may want to browse your application from different locations (local, internet, intranet) and check IE -> Tools -> Compatibility View Settings for the option "Display Intranet sites in Compatibility View". Turn it off and refresh to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the link tag that references your css file out of your **master page's  contentPlaceHolder** with id **head** as shown below,

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>Title1</title>
  <link href="~/css/layout.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" runat="server" />

   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

This fixed my issues while running through iis..